# How do you add join a table using Criteria in yii for CActiveDataProvider?

Tags: yii

I have three tables in my db tbl_project, tbl_employee and tbl_user_assignment.
I need to write CDbCriteria on below sql query

```
SELECT * from tbl_project
INNER JOIN tbl_user_assignment 
ON tbl_user_assignment.project_id = tbl_project.id;
JOIN tbl_employee 
ON tbl_employee.id = tbl_user_assignment.user_id
WHERE tbl_employee = 8
```

i have already created model class for these three tables as Project,Employee,Userassign respectively.

my data provider code is

```
  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project',array(
                       'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>3,
                        ),
  ));
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Provide Model Class Name and Fix Your Query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `criteria` which contains a `with`. Use the relationship name(s) you've defined in your models.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project',array(
  'pagination'=>array(
  'pageSize'=>3,

  'criteria'=>array(
    'with'=>array(
      'userassign',
      'employee',
    )
  )
));
```

You'll obviously need to change the above to match your personally requirements.

More about criteria [on the yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7420-undestanding-relational-queries-with-cactivedataprovider/)